# FluentValidation how to check for Length if string is not null?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm testing a `PUT` with two `string`:

```
company.CurrencyCode = request.CurrencyCode ?? company.CurrencyCode;
company.CountryIso2 = request.Country ?? company.CountryIso2;
```

and I tried with a rule like:

```
public UpdateCompanyValidator()
{
    RuleSet(ApplyTo.Put, () =>
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.CountryIso2)
              .Length(2)
              .When(x => !x.Equals(null));

        RuleFor(r => r.CurrencyCode)
              .Length(3)
              .When(x => !x.Equals(null));
    });
}
```

as I don't mind to get a `null` on those properties, but I would like to test the `Length` **when** the property is not a `null`.

What is the best way to apply rules when a property is `nullable` and we just want to test if it's not null?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One of the ways would be:

```
public class ModelValidation : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidation()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Country).Must(x => x == null || x.Length >= 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I prefer the following syntax:

```
When(m => m.CountryIso2 != null,
     () => {
         RuleFor(m => m.CountryIso2)
             .Length(2);
     );
```

Answer (score 3):

Best syntax for me:

```
RuleFor(t => t.DocumentName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("message")
            .DependentRules(() =>
                {
                    RuleFor(d2 => d2.DocumentName).MaximumLength(200)
                        .WithMessage(string.Format(stringLocalizer[""message""], 200));
                });
```